# Fetch list of objects with distinct() in django

Tags: django, distinct

I have a database with tags for an image gallery. They contain the fields 'id', 'picture_id' and 'tag'. I am trying to build a list of all tags, but without listing the same tag twice. This I know I can do with distinct() in the queryset, but using this with all() only throws an error telling me that backend database does not support it. (I'm using MySQL).

If I use values_list('id','tag') I don't get that error. I don't get any error at all actually. But I don't get anything I can print out in my template either.

The queryset is written like this:

```
tags = Tag.objects.values_list('id', 'tag').distinct().order_by('tag')
```

In template I can try to print this with:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <p>{{ tag.id }}: {{ tag.tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a long(ish) row of ':' signs, but nothing on its right or left side. This indicates to me that there are stuff in my list, but I can't seem to use it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It's worth noting that I tried doing these things in a Shell and when printing out tags there I get a list of objects that seemingly consists of both id and tag, but I still can't seem to get it output in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_list` will create a list of tuples, not dictionaries, so using dictionary notation won't work. [Check out the the docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list-fields)

> ... instead of returning a list of dictionaries, it returns a list of tuples. Each tuple contains the value from the respective field passed into the values_list() call -- so the first item is the first field, etc. For example:

```
>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')
[(1, u'First entry'), ...]
```

So, instead you should do :

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <p>{{ tag.0 }}: {{ tag.1 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem with not being able to see the post, so thanks! I will mark this as an accepted answer when I can (6 minutes), but I still can't seem to both use distinct to weed out unique tags, and also be able to have and use 'id' as well. Do you know of a way to do this, or is the only way to create a list or something manually in views.py before sending that to the template?

Comment: were you calling `distinct()` or `distinct('tag')`? The latter might have been causing an error due to a bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17974

Comment: I was aware of the error that follows using distinct('tag'). I think the problem is that having values_list('id','tag') and then doing a distinct() may then look at unique combinations of both id and tag, which just will always be unique of course.

Comment: A friend of mine made a smart comment to my problem: "If you need this functionality then you have a "bad" database structure." After a bit of consideration I found that he was right. Problem solved. Thanks anyway :)